# Way to interface with Intel's new DRNG (RDRAND instruction) from C#?

Tags: c#, random, cryptography, intel, rdrand

I'm looking to consume Intel's Digital Random Number Generator (the RDRAND instruction in Ivy Bridge) from a C# assembly.  I've looked at cpp libs but I was hoping there was a more "managed" solution.  Any ideas?

Comment: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2617425-provide-support-for-the-new-rdrand-instruction-for

Comment: I understand your position on this not following SO guidelines but it's a useful question with a useful answer.  It seems like a less-destructive fix would have been to slightly reword the question.  I notice some of your own questions have been closed for similar reasons so I suspect you know how frustrating that is.

Comment: Since there appears to be continued interest in this, check out: http://blog.viathefalcon.net/2012/10/03/using-intels-secure-key-rdrand-in-ms-visual-c-2010/

Answer (score 1):

The best I can find is here:

- [Rdrand manual and library (Windows* version)](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/user-manual-for-the-rdrand-library-windows-version)
- [Rdrand manual and library (Linux* and OS X* version)](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/user-manual-for-the-rdrand-library-linux-version)

You can download and compile (link, etc) your own. If you know someone who knows C++, write some `extern` methods for `P/Invoke`s from C#.

Comment: Yeah, I know C++ I'm just lazy :)

Comment: Actually, I'm lazy and the only published libraries appear to be compiled with Intel and I'm having trouble linking to them with Visual Studio.