# When do I use std::random_device?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

According to the standard, `std::random_device` works the following way:

> `result_type operator()();`
>
> > *Returns:* A non-deterministic random value, uniformly distributed between `min()` and `max()`, inclusive. It is implementation-defined
> >     how these values are generated.

And there are a couple of ways you can use it. To seed an engine:

```
std::mt19937 eng(std::random_device{}());
```

As an engine in itself:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<> uid(1, 10);
std::cout << dist(dev);
```

Because it is implementation-defined, it doesn't sound as strong as say `std::seed_seq` or `srand(time(nullptr))`. Do I prefer to use it as a seed, as an engine or not at all?

Comment: Unfortunately, you do have to be careful. For example, [MinGW doesn't implement `std::random_device` well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18880654/10077).

Comment: I would go for the first option, but it also depends on the quality of the engine you want to seed it with.

Comment: It could well be stronger than those techniques which are not cryptographically strong. Visual C++ for example uses [RtlGenRandom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387694.aspx).

Comment: I doubt you'll get a meaningful answer without specifying a compiler/platform on this one -- otherwise the best answer is to check your compiler's documentation for specifics.

Comment: The source that `random_device` uses to fetch the random bits is implementation defined. So, if your implementation uses `/dev/random` instead of `/dev/urandom`, the call might block until you replenish the entropy pool, which might mean you'll spend a lot of time wiggling your mouse :)

Answer (score 14):

Generally speaking, `std::random_device` should be the source of the most truly random information you can access on your platform. That being said, accessing it is much slower than `std::mt19937` or what not.

The correct behavior is to use `std::random_device` to seed something like `std::mt19937`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `std::random_device` could run out of entropy if you try to get a lot of numbers from it. That could cause it to block until you move the mouse or something.

Comment: *Should* be, but sometimes isn't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880654/why-do-i-get-same-sequence-for-everyrun-with-stdrandom-device-with-mingw-gcc4