# How to use a random generator as a class member in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I'm trying with no luck to use the std::mt19937 generator as a class member but I always get the same result. This is an example of what I'm trying.

```
class Level 
{
public:
    Level();
private:
   int generateTokenType();
   std::mt19937 m_mt;
   std::random_device m_randomdevice;
};

Level::Level(): m_mt(m_randomdevice())
{
}

int Level::generateTokenType()
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 10);
    return dist(m_mt);
}
```

What I want, is to maintain the generator created and ask for numbers during program execution.

-- Edit --
Following Cornstalks answer I did that:

```
class Level
{
public:
   Level();
private:
   int generateTokenType();
   std::mt19937 m_mt;
};
Level::Level(): m_mt((std::random_device())())
{
    for(auto i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout<<generateTokenType()<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

int Level::generateTokenType()
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 10);
    return dist(m_mt);
}
```

But on every execution I get the same numbers...

Comment: First, no need to be harsh. And second, I'm not getting a compiler warning.

Comment: As an advice, try enabling all warnings. For `gcc` or `clang` use `-Wall`. If you use an IDE, select an appropriate option in the project/environment setting. This should help you in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Move `std::random_device m_randomdevice;` **before** `std::mt19937 m_mt;`.

In C++, members are constructed/initialized in the order that they're declared in the class. Your constructor is calling `m_randomdevice()` *before* `m_randomdevice` has even been constructed.

Alternatively, get rid of the `m_randomdevice` member. You could just do `m_mt((std::random_device())())` to initialize `m_mt`.

Comment: Something is crazy, I did what you said but I get always the same numbers. I checked the code here [link](https://ideone.com/O7hF1u) and it works ok, but .. maybe it's something related to MinGW?

Comment: @FrameBuffer: mingw has had a broken std::random_device. Perhaps it is still broken. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880654/why-do-i-get-same-sequence-for-everyrun-with-stdrandom-device-with-mingw-gcc4

Comment: Yes definitely it's broken in the version I'm using .. well,  I will try to workaround that.. thank you. I will mark this answer as correct, because this mingw thing is not related to my question.