# Generate random numbers with uniform distribution (getting same number in loop)

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I need to generate random numbers between two specified numbers in a loop with a uniform distribution. I am using the `random` library of C++11.

My problem is that I keep getting the same number in the loop. It is required that the number generated on every loop pass be different. Code below:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

double randnum (double a, double b)
{
  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution (a,b);
  double num=distribution(generator);

  return num;
}


int main()
{
    int np=100;

    double umin =0;
    double umax=0.5;
    double u[np];

    for (int i=0;i<np;i++)
    {
        u[i]=randnum(umin,umax);
        cout<<u[i]<<endl;
    }    
}
```

Please help.  Any advice on generating random number by any alternative means is welcome, but it must have a uniform distribution.

Comment: Don't construct an RNG on every function call. Construct it once.

Comment: You're not seeding your `generator` properly. Try using [`random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) for doing so, but be warned, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18880689/2851815)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Both solutions work. Although generating a static function feels the most convenient (as suggested in the answer). I understand that the numbers generated will be pseudo random, but it will solve the purpose of my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The random number engines in the Standard Library are *pseudo-random*, i.e. deterministic in how their internal state is initialized and mutated. This means that each function call will get a fresh new generator that will continue to give the same number over and over again.

Just make the `generator` a `static` function variable so that its state can evolve over different function calls.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

double randnum (double a, double b)
{
  static std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution (a,b);
  return distribution(generator);
}

int main()
{
    const int np=100;

    double umin =0;
    double umax=0.5;
    double u[np];

    for (int i=0;i<np;i++)
    {
        u[i]=randnum(umin,umax);
        cout<<u[i]<<endl;
    }    
}
```

**[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ffc4a9ab30ab918)**.

Note, you will get the same sequence of numbers for each run of your compiled program. To get more random behavior across program invocations, you can use e.g. `std::random_device`.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. This is excellent solution. I am a newbie in C++. Didnt know there was anything like static function. This is gonna help me a lot!!

Comment: @nash.ouroboro yes, seeding will do that

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add to the 1st answer:
Using static function will generate different numbers in the loop but would generate the same set of random numbers on every run. I avoided this by using time as seed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

double randnum (double a, double b)
{
  unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  static std::default_random_engine generator (seed);
  //static std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution (a,b);
  return distribution(generator);
}

int main()
{
    const int np=100;

    double umin =0;
    double umax=0.5;
    double u[np];

    for (int i=0;i<np;i++)
    {
        u[i]=randnum(umin,umax);
        cout<<u[i]<<endl;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Note: using time as a seed is great for simulations and the like, but don't use it as a seed for cryptographic applications, as that's too easily brute-forced.  Also, it may be a good idea to log the used value in case you ever need to repeat a particular run (for debugging, perhaps).  Again, not if you're doing cryptography!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am using it for fluid dynamics simulation and therefore  the time seed, or any for that matter, should be good for my case.