# std::random_device not working in g++

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I'm using g++ with MinGW in Windows to compile my c++ code, which looks like this:

```
std::mt19937_64 rng(std::random_device{}());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, words.size() - 1);
std::string curr = words[dist(rng)];
```

as you can see, this extracts a random word from an array of std::string, but when I optput that word, its always the same, i've realised that the problem lies in std::random_device, which outputs always the same number.

why is this happening? how can I fix it?

gcc version 5.3.0

I use vs code for programming if it could help

And of course i properly include random

Comment: What version of G++?

Comment: @Mocoma [edit] the question to include necessary information

Comment: Are you constructing a new `random_device` each time, or do you construct a single one and then use it repeatedly?

Comment: @JohnZwinck gcc version 5.3.0

Comment: @JohnZwinck  construct a new one beacuse the program itself only uses it one time. For checking that the random device generates a new number every time, i created it another time

Comment: Are you using `MinGW` on Windows? (its known to be broken)

Comment: @Galik Yes, MinGW 32 bit

Comment: An implementation of `random_device` in MinGW:  https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get the same sequence for every run with std::random\_device with mingw gcc4.8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880654/why-do-i-get-the-same-sequence-for-every-run-with-stdrandom-device-with-mingw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `std::random_device` on MinGW.  More specifically, you are creating a new instance every time you want a random number.  This usage is not supported (or rather, does not produce random numbers).  See [Why do I get the same sequence for every run with std::random_device with mingw gcc4.8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880654/why-do-i-get-the-same-sequence-for-every-run-with-stdrandom-device-with-mingw) for the fact that MinGW has this behavior, but to fix your particular code, you can do something like this:

```
std::mt19937_64 rng(std::random_device{}());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, words.size() - 1);

for (int ii = 0; ii < 100; ++ii) {
    std::string curr = words[dist(rng)];
}
```

That is, use the same `random_device` repeatedly, rather than just once.  And consider seeding it, or using a different RNG, if randomness is important between program runs.