# <random> generates same number in Windows, but not in Linux

Tags: random, pseudo-element

I do not why, but in Windows (with MinGW) this code generates for 3/4 time the same pseudo-random number.
I think that is because I set badly the seed, but I can not correct it.

Thank you for your help.

Here there is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{   

double Nprove = 50.0;
double p = 0.2;  
const int Ncampioni = 100; // number of samples

int cappa = 0;
double sample[Ncampioni];

unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

std::mt19937 gen(seed);
std::binomial_distribution<> d(Nprove, 0.9);

for(cappa = 0; cappa < Ncampioni; cappa = cappa +1){ 
    sample[cappa] = d(gen);
    std::cout << cappa << "," << sample[cappa] << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile for me.

Comment: @Rob Try it here: https://ideone.com/W3gVbV

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get the same sequence for every run with std::random\_device with mingw gcc4.8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880654/why-do-i-get-the-same-sequence-for-every-run-with-stdrandom-device-with-mingw)

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain my problem well. Now I have midified the text.