# How can i choose certain characters in a char function?

Tags: c++

So i have been making a password generator but i cant split the characters in the char that i have made to store the characters for the password:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char letras[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
    string senha;
    int tamanho;
    int num;

    cout<<"escreve a quantidade de letrasdsa"<<endl;
    cin >> tamanho;

    srand(time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho ; i++){


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can you please help me complete the last part?

Comment: Seeding the RNG from `time(0)` is a terrible idea from a security point of view. So is using the stdlib `srand` and `rand` functions.

Comment: Use random function

Comment: you are using `std::string` so why not also for `letras` ? Also the question is not quite clear. Why you cannot split characters? What does it mean to "split characters" ? Can you include example input and output in the question please?

Comment: What do you mean by splitting the characters? If you need a random letter from your array, you'd go like `letras[random_value % 26]`. I'd personally prefer to use a string, though, allowing you to use a proper dynamic size. In any case, you should get rid of that habit of having non english variable names. Also, you should really initialize your variables.

Comment: Do you know how to choose a random value between 0 and 25?  If not, then write a very small `main` program to get familiar with how random number generator functions work and choosing a value between a range of integers.  You seeded the random generator by using `srand()`, but nowhere do you do anything with `rand()` (let's forget that `rand()` is bad, but you get the point).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to generate a random password of length `tamanho` out of these characters, use [`std::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) algorithm:

```
const char letras[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
std::size_t tamanho = 10;

std::string senha;
senha.reserve(tamanho);

std::sample(std::begin(letras), std::end(letras) - 1, std::back_inserter(senha), 
    tamanho, std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});

std::cout << senha; // Sample output: bdefjkmosx
```

`1` is subtracted from `std::end(letras)`, because string literals are zero-terminated, and we don't want to include the `'\0'` character into the password. For `const std::string letras = "...";` you don't need that subtraction.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dSGQ9W)

---

**Edit!**

If you try to generate a password of 26 letters or more, you'll see that the previous solution is not correct. It does generate short random passwords, but

> If `n` is greater than the number of elements in the sequence, selects `last-first` elements. The algorithm is stable (preserves the relative order of the selected elements) only if `PopulationIterator` meets the requirements of `LegacyForwardIterator`.

That is, it limits the password length and preserves the order of letters making it impossible to get a password like "z....a".

Possible fix is to ask `std::sample` for 1 character `tamanho` times:

```
std::string senha;
senha.reserve(tamanho);

std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()};
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(senha), tamanho, [&]() {
    char ch;
    std::sample(std::begin(letras), std::end(letras) - 1, &ch, 1, gen);
    return ch; 
});
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4h4J8c)

or

```
std::string senha(tamanho, ' ');

std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()};
for (auto& ch : senha)
    std::sample(std::begin(letras), std::end(letras) - 1, &ch, 1, gen);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/BSBGsK)

**Edit 2.**

If you don't have access to C++17 compiler, you can use `std::uniform_int_distribution` to get C++11 solution:

```
std::string senha;
senha.reserve(tamanho);

std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> d(0, std::end(letras) - 
                                                std::begin(letras) - 2);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < tamanho; ++i)
    senha.push_back(letras[d(gen)]);
```

Comment: Where is the output in your demo? Ok, I spy it there. Well hidden, but futile!

Comment: @JaideepShekhar, it should be at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @JaideepShekhar "futile" ? Not sure but I think either me or you should look that word up in a dictionary again

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I had meant [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/352501). But yeah, I see it was perhaps not the best choice.

Comment: @JaideepShekhar thats also what I understood. It appears a bit unkind to tell the answerer that the result is useless, because that is exactly the result OP was asking for. Nevermind, not my buisness ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I believe you misunderstand. I referred to the _output_ of the demo, which was "hidden" from me, rather than to the answer. I am sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: I mean, your code works and makes clever use of some STL functions, but wouldn't it be more effective to show the guy how to use random generators in general? Given that the guy did not manage to use the basic random functions, it is pretty clear that he is a beginner, right?

Comment: @Aziuth, I don't know what is the best strategy here. The question about using RNG in general has been answered multiple times already.

Comment: My compiler keeps saying that "sample" is not a member of "std"

Comment: @Bernardo Which compiler do you use and which version? `std::sample` requires C++17.

Comment: @Bernardo, I updated the answer with C++11 solution.

Comment: i just checked and i use c++11 , so it worked! Thank you.

Comment: But just a question here: is it possible to make the result change everytime i run the program?

Comment: @Bernardo, it looks like you're using [broken `random_device` implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880654/why-do-i-get-the-same-sequence-for-every-run-with-stdrandom-device-with-mingw). Simplest (but not an ideal) solution: `std::mt19937 gen{static_cast<std::uint_fast32_t>(std::time(nullptr))};`.