# Random number generation in C++

Tags: c++, random

I've written this code using the  library in C++.

```
# include <math.h>
# include <iostream>
# include <random>

double srand(){
   std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0, 1.0);
   std::random_device rd;
   std::default_random_engine generator(rd());
   return distribution(generator);
}

using namespace std;

int main(){
   for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
   cout << srand() << endl;
   }
}
```

But every time I run the code, I get this result:

> 0.687363
>   0.687363
>   0.687363
>   0.687363
>   0.687363
>   0.687363
>   0.687363
>   0.687363
>   0.687363
>   0.687363

Comment: First, don't seed every time you want a random number. Second, what is your platform? MinGW, by chance?

Comment: The first post recommended by Nathan Oliver solved my issue.

Comment: I was asking about the platform because MinGW's implementation of `std::random_device` is [notorious for always giving the same sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18880654/10077).

Comment: Yes, I'm using MinGW compiler.