# How to do random shuffling of an array

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to generate numbers between range of 1 to n to create test cases for my program. So i created an array of size n  and then stored it in array then used`random_shuffle` But it's actually not random it always gives same series of number. it changes series like after 3 or 4 shuffling.

So is there any better way to do it. My basic problem is just to create a series of number from [1, n] in any random manner.

```
int n = 9;

   int arr[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

   int k = 2;

   while(k--)
    random_shuffle(arr, arr+ n);

    for(auto x :arr)
        cout << x <<" ";

Output : 5 4 8 9 1 6 3 2 7 
So for either k = 1 or k = 2 it gives same output.
```

Comment: Did you remember to seed the randomizer?

Comment: `random_shuffle`, or now just `shuffle` is the way to go.  Can you share a [mre]?

Comment: I recommend adding a [mcve]. Without one there best we can do is make guesses.

Comment: Also note that `std::random_device` is [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880654/why-do-i-get-the-same-sequence-for-every-run-with-stdrandom-device-with-mingw) on some platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), `std::random_shuffle` commonly uses `std::rand()` as randomizer, which would require setting seed with `srand()` first.

However, `std::shuffle` accepts the generators from `<random>` library (which are superior to `rand()` unless you are using MinGW older than 9.3)

Example of usage from cppreference (linked above):

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());

    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: `std::random_device rd;` as a seed is problematic.  Not all implementations give you a non-deterministic source.

Comment: `random_device` has a usable implementation in MinGW's port of gcc9.3.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think it is more accurate to say that MinGW is a problematic compiler because its `std::ramdom_device` is broken. Though I believe they have finally fixed it.

Comment: This works for me as it seems to gives new combination of array.

Answer (score 2):

Computers cannot generate true random numbers. Although there are techniques to generate something close to true randomness by for example measuring background radiation, generally random numbers generated by programs are pseudo random numbers.

A pseudo random sequence starting from some state is always identical to another pseudo random sequence starting from the same state, and using the same algorithm. In order to generate a different sequence, you need to start with a different state. The ability to reproduce a random sequence repeatedly is actually quite a useful thing to do in some cases.

In case of `std::random_shuffle`, the initial state is set with the `std::srand` function. If you pass a different number to `std::srand`, then you get a different pseudo random sequence and thus a different shuffle. A typical simple approach is to use the current time of day using `std::time` function. But take into consideration that the time changes only once every second.