# std::random - On Windows always I get the same numbers

Tags: c++, linux, windows, random, g++

After compilation, the program always returns the same results. Unpredictably, the code works correctly on Linux ...

```cpp
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribut(1, 6);

    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << distribut(gen) << ' ';
    }
```

Compiler specification:

```
❯ g++ --version
g++.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: `std::random_device` might give the same seed to `std::mt19937`every time, as some implementations are just `return constant;`

Comment: Have a read of https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85494 _"Anyway, it should be fixed for mingw-w64 in the gcc-9-branch, so for the GCC 9.2 release"_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get the same sequence for every run with std::random\_device with mingw gcc4.8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880654/why-do-i-get-the-same-sequence-for-every-run-with-stdrandom-device-with-mingw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `std::random_device` object (which you are using to seed your `std::mt19937`) *may* produce the same seed, each time (although it doesn't on my Windows 10 + Visual Studio test platform).

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) (bolding mine):

> std::random_device may be implemented in terms of an
> implementation-defined pseudo-random number engine if a
> non-deterministic source (e.g. a hardware device) is not available to
> the implementation. **In this case each std::random_device object may
> generate the same number sequence**.

Here's a possible solution using the 'classic' call to `time(nullptr)` as the seed, which also avoids the use of the 'intermediate' `std::random_device` object to generate that seed (though there will be other options to get that seed):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 gen(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribut(1, 6);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << distribut(gen) << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```